# Succes and failure probability for dependant trials.

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains

Suppose a sender sends information to a destination.

The maximum number of transmissions is two.

If the first transmission is a failure, the information is sent only one more time.

Now in the first transmission, we have 2 cases : either the destination decode correctly with probability $P_1$ or it does not decode with probability $Q_1$.

Now, if the destination decodes correctly the received message ( this happen with probability $P$), then we don't transmit again this message (only one transmission).

If it does not decode correctly, failure to decode (this happen with probability $Q$), so now we go to the second trial ( or second transmission).

But now when we send in the second transmission we use the first received message in error and the new (the second transmission), which mean the two trial are dependent, and also we will have the probability of successful in second trial $P_2$  or probability of failure after in second trail $Q_2$.

So we have two trials :

Trial one has success probability $P_1$ and failure probability $Q_1$.

Trial two also has success probability $P_2$ (after first failure transmission which depends of first failure trial  $Q_1$) and failure $Q_2$.

The value of $P_1$ is $P_1=e^{-\theta}$, $\theta$ is a real number.

My question now : the two trials are dependent, SO is there any probability law or distribution to get $Q_1, P_2$ and $Q_2$.

I mean to compute the value of $Q_1, P_2$ and $Q_2$.

Can we use "2 State Markov depended  cahin" and how ?

I hear about ""Geometric distribution of order k with a reward"" and

""Compound Geometric Distribution of Order $k$"".

If anyone can help me, please

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is $P_2$ defined?

Comment: The  problem is $P_2$ because after first failure decoding attempt, here we use the information from the first attempt and then we combine with the second attempt so we can say like I have threshold $S=0.77$, in first attempt i receive message and does not exceed the threshold, for example, we say amount $0.66$ wich mean i fail to decode this is $Q_1$, no I wait for the second attempt and combine with first receive amount if the first and second amounts sum exceed $0.77$ now i succsufly decode, this is $P_2$, if the summed dose not exceed so failure with probability $Q_2$.

Comment: What is $S$? Can you please define all your variables clearly?

Comment: From what I managed to gather so far you need overall success probability over certain threshold, say, $t$. Basically you need $P_1+Q_1P_2>t$, which is easily computed. The issue now is that $P_2$ likely has similar parameters to $P_1$ but how that is computed is completely absent from your preamble.

Comment: If you don't have some clear objective(s) for us to work on then I'm afraid I also don't know how I can help you...

Comment: So can you please tell me how we use 2-State Markov chain to model failure and succeed probability for independet then i will try to do for dependent. What about "Geometric distribution of order k with a reward"

Comment: I am not at the level to use Markov chain yet, but I can say very confidently that there is no need for geometric distribution here since we only have at most 2 trials. For the same reason, Markov chain is likely not needed too. 

Now that you have mentioned threshold level, how is the threshold level distributed?

And, please correct the typos and grammatical errors in your responses or at least keep it readable. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to say. If you are not providing info in a way that is understandable how can other people help you solve the problem?

Comment: ok ok yes we can also use any think of threshold and we can also make him a random variable. I just need some value in which $P2$ depend on the first transmission. I think that for example, 2 attempt we have a probability of successful higher than one transmission since when we sum the amount of receive information we approach to threshold or i am wrong?

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are asking. $P_2$ itself is $P\left(\text{2nd transmission is successful}\mid\text{1st transmission is unsuccessful}\right)$.

Comment: yes is like this it possible work for me this case

Comment: So what are you trying to compute then? All I have managed to gather from you so far is that.

AND PLEASE TYPE IN READABLE ENGLISH.

Comment: we can say like this , $A$ the recived amount in first attemt and $B$ in second attempt so $P_2=P(A+B>=thresoul| A<thresoul)$

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: SO i asking ho we compute $P_2,Q_1$ and $Q_2$

Comment: $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are simple. For $P_2$, use the law of total probability.

Comment: ok thankyou so much

Comment: but how ? total law of probability

Comment: Google. Wikipedia. Have you done any research yourself at all?

Comment: Hi  i am really sorry but i have spand 2h reading total law bayes theorem and i dident know how we compute so please can you help me please